# Android: how do I right-justify a TextView?

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

I am trying to right-justify the TextView "Due:" on the Subhead line in the CardView image below.  I'd like the text to be just to the left of the "11/30/2100" date.  Layout code is below.  What am I missing here?

[image]

layout.xml

```
...
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardBlankText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:singleLine="true"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardBlankText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cardBlankText2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"            
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:singleLine="true"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardBlankText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cardBlankText3"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cardBlankText3"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="Due:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:singleLine="true"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardBlankText5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cardBlankText4"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cardBlankText4"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="duedate"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:singleLine="true"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"  />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: android:layout_toLeftOf="id"

Comment: android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/"

Comment: I added "layout_toLeftOf="@+if/cardBlankText5" to the TextView #4.  The app crashes with logcat: "Circular dependencies cannot exist in Relative Layout".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try with below code.**

`Replace in your xml.`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardBlankText2"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardBlankText3"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cardBlankText2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardBlankText4"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cardBlankText5"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Due:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardBlankText5"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="duedate"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is screen shot how it Looks with Aboce XML.

[image]

Comment: Ok I will try the above.

Comment: Does the order of the lines make a difference?  I noticed you put the "style" code as the second row for each TextView.

Comment: @AJW  There is no need to change the code with `Linear Layout` just try this code. I have made some change in text views.

Comment: @AJW Nope it's just i have formatted xml code that's why it takes automatically.

Comment: Ok, I am trying now.

Comment: @AJW Yes please try and check and let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: Looks good!  I agree that I did not want to change to a LinearLayout because that was justing nesting another layout layer in the code.  Basically you anchored the Text5 to the right and bottom of the parent and then just put the Text4 to its left, correct?

Comment: @AJW Exactly right :). Please upvote and accept the answer if it helpful to you thanks :).

Comment: @AJW Glad to help you enjoy :).

Answer (score 2):

Just change `gravity` to `layout_gravity`, Your requirement should be done.

`android:gravity` **with** `android:layout_gravity`.

Comment: For each of the TextViews or only the cardBlankText4?

Answer (score 1):

Use LinearLayout, check below code:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkSelected"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cardBlankText2"
                    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Test1"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cardBlankText3"
                        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="Below 2"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cardBlankText4"
                        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="Due:"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cardBlankText5"
                        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="11/30/2100"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it by making LinearLayout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"  >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkSelected"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"  />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cardBlankText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chkSelected"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/chkSelected"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:singleLine="true"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"  />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cardBlankText3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cardBlankText2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chkSelected"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/chkSelected"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:singleLine="true"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"  />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cardBlankText4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Due:"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:singleLine="true"
                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"  />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cardBlankText5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="duedate"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:singleLine="true"
                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"  />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the TextView with id `cardBlankText5`, replace

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cardBlankText4"
android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cardBlankText4"
```

with

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
```

And for the TextView with id `cardBlankText4`, replace

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cardBlankText3"
android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cardBlankText3"
```

with

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cardBlankText5"
android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/cardBlankText5"
```

Comment: I tried.  The TextView #4 does not show up.  The "Due:" is missing.

Answer (score 0):

//You given alignment of date and dateString from the left textview alignment that the reason your Due: string textView start from left 
you can easily solve this problem by giving right alignment for date 
and Due: string  textView according  to date.
//replace this code with your old code.
Hope it will helpful for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardBlankText2"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardBlankText3"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cardBlankText2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chkSelected"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardBlankText4"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cardBlankText5"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Due:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardBlankText5"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="duedate"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</RelativeLayout>
```